# filesystem from ISO

Tags: filesystem

Installation of Linux yields the filesystem which consists of folders like bin, boot, dev etc.

When one extract a iso file, files like autorun.inf, preeseed, dists, install , pics etc appears.

How can one see the Linux filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the Ubuntu file system from the Ubuntu ISO image you might want to look inside (archive) file `casper/filesystem.squashfs` from the Ubuntu ISO image.

Un-archiving this file on the target file system is actually part of the Ubuntu installation procedure (performed by the Ubuntu installer, which does other things as well so in the end one can get a running system).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You download the ubuntu*.iso image from the community, then mount that iso image in your system. Open the mounted directory you can see the Hierarchy of the iso image tree-like boot, casper, dists, EFI and pool etc. The casper/filesystem.squashfs contain all directories(usr,lib,sys and dev etc). once you unsquashfs the file-system using the below command then you can see what you expected.

$ unsquashfs -d path_for_where_the_file_unsquasfs path_for_filesystem.squashfs

or double click the downloaded iso image it's automatically mounted then you continue unsquashfs steps.